# An error occured while processing your request

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I've just taken this tutorial about how to create a .NET Core with SQL DB.I get the following error message the webapp created as part of this process. I would appreciate some pointers as to what can be done to fix the problem indicated in error. Thanks

Error.

> An error occurred while processing your request. Development Mode
>   Swapping to Development environment will display more detailed
>   information about the error that occurred.  Development environment
>   should not be enabled in deployed applications, as it can result in
>   sensitive information from exceptions being displayed to end users.
>   For local debugging, development environment can be enabled by setting
>   the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable to Development, and
>   restarting the application.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set the environment variable inside the web app on azure.

Open the Application Settings blade and go down to the "Application Settings" section to add the "**ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT**" and "**Development**".

Refer to this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394698.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which provides an overview of the tasks that are required to publish a visual studio web project to a server where others can access the application over the Internet.

Also, you could use [azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-azure-webapp-using-vs) to connect to web app on azure.